# ASP.NET MVC - Can't log into the system using IE after publishing to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, authentication, iis-6

I have a project created in ASP.NET, MVC 3, C#. It works in every browser when testing it on my dev machine, once published it works fine in chrome and every other browser apart from IE.

The problem - I am trying to login to my site but the web site just refreshes with the return url included in the url.

I have tried the following:

Removed helpers
Removed webMatrix

Added the following to the web.config:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
```

Checked my internet options settings, they are currently set to medium-low and Enable Protected mode, I have also turned this off and had no joy.

I have another web site that has been deployed to the same internal server and works fine 
in IE.

Does anyone have any idea what would be causing this problem?

Here is my Web.config:

http://pastebin.com/0b5FBuTs

I am using IE9

THanks

Comment: Do you actually have a connection string? The `<connectionStrings>` section of your `web.config` is completely empty in the pastebin link and yet it is looking for a connection string called `ApplicationServices`.

Comment: yes, I have a connection string, I took it out as I've heard that putting connection strings and other company data such as password is not a good idea

Comment: I guessed it was that. Sometimes you can just change the userid, server name and password to be 'xxx' or something. I presume you are using the same database for the app as for the user credentials are you? Only it's common for it to default to using `aspnetdb` for the application services in addition to your normal app database. Just a thought.